# Can't reach except block in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to loop through a certain line of code until any exception or keyboard interruption occurs. But I can not reach the exception block whenever any exception occurs or due to keyboard interruption. 
How can I modify my code so that I could actually reach in case of  exception being thrown?

```
def run():
    lidar = RPLidar(PORT_NAME)

    iterator = lidar.iter_scans(50000)
    time.sleep(2)
    environment(iterator)

    while True:

        try:
            print('Hi')
            update_line(iterator)

        except Exception or KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("exception occur. Run again")
            #lidar = RPLidar(PORT_NAME)
            lidar.stop_motor()
            lidar.stop()
            lidar.disconnect()

            break





if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that code actually runs. When you say `except Exception or KeyboardInterrupt` you are saying only take the first thing here that evaluates to True.  Since bool(Exception) is True you are only going to catch Exceptions. To catch multiple types of exceptions you would write it like this:

```
try:

except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
```

It might not be triggering or non-keyboard exceptions because the exception you are trying to catch derives from `BaseException` and not `Exception`. To fix that change `Exception` to `BaseException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def run():

    while True:

        try:
            print('Hi')
            function_doesnt_exist(iterator)

        except Exception or KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("exception occur. Run again")
            break





if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

When I intentionally call function that doesn't exist in your while loop it calls exception : exception occur. Run again 
Perhaps you didn't generate an error properly therefore no exception is called

Also , Exception or KeyboardInterrupt means Exception since Exception includes KeyboardInterrupt and u handle them in same manner
so If you just want to catch Keyboard Interrupt then go for:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Or if you want to handle general exception and Keyboard one different do something like this:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("don't press ctrl+C")
    pass
except:
    print("exception occured")
    pass
```